# Changing properties of container view

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, tabview, nstabview

I have a tabView with let's say 3 tabs, each of the tabViewItems contains a webView. I want to set the title of each tab as the `document.title` of the HTML page each webView is rendering.

So basically, each `NSTabViewItem` has a `Webview`, via `[tabViewItem setView:webView];`.
Now, on the `didFinishLoadForFrame` delegate of the webviews, I can retrieve the title of the HTML page by doing a `NSString *title = [sender stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"]`. I only have access to the `sender` object, so my question is how can I get the `NSTabViewItem` *containing* my sender. In other words, what should I put inside the `< >`s

```
[<getNSTabViewItemFromSender:sender> setLabel:title]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parent of any NSView by [sending it `-superview`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/superview).

Comment: Well actually here it's not exactly the parent, because: 1) i did a `[tabViewItem setView:webView]` so `tabViewItem` is not the superview of my webview, and 2) superview returns a NSView object and what I want is a NSTabViewItem.

Answer (score 0):

Since your web view object is setup as the view for the tab, you can find the tab item that is using your specific web view.

You can implement this as a category on `NSTabView` (something like this)...

```
- (NSTabViewItem*)tabViewItemWithView:(NSView*)view {
    for (NSTabViewItem *item in [self tabViewItems]) {
        if (item.view == view) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Then, you can set the label for the tab item that contains your web view.

```
[[tabView tabViewItemWithView:webView] setLabel:label];
```